# Azure search solr index definition for supporting multiple markets

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, solr, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-search

I am building a product catalog for an e-comm website. I am having a requirement to build a azure search/solr/elastic search based index. The problem is saving the market specific attributes. The website is supporting 109 markets and there is each market specific data like ratings, price, views, wish-listed, etc. that I need to save in the index eg: Product1 will have 109 ratings(rating is different in each market)/109 prices(price might be different in each market) corresponding to 109 markets. Also I will have to use this attributes to add a boosting function so that when people are searching for this, products with higher view/ratings surfaces up. How do I design the index definition to support this? Can I achieve this by 1 index doc per product or do I have to create 1 index doc per market? Some pointers will be very helpful. I have spent couple of days on this and could not reach to a conclusion that is optimized for this use case. Thank you!

My proposed index definition:

```html
-id
-mktUSA
--mktId
--rating
--views
--price
  ...
-mktCanada
--mktId
--rating
--views
--price
  ...
-locales
--En
--Fr
--Zh
  ...
...other properties
```

The problem with this approach is configuring a magnitude scoring functions inside scoring profile, to boost products based on the market

Say eg: If user is from Canada, only the Canada based rating/views should be considered and not the other market ratings while Cognitive search is calculating the search relevance score.

Is there any possible work around this? Elastic search has a neat solution of [Function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)  that can be used to configure the scoring function dynamically

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your problem is that you want to have a single index with products that support 109 different markets. Many different properties for your Product model can then be market-specific. Your concern is that the model gets to big, or if it's a scalable design. It is. You can have 1000+ properties without a problem.

I have built a similar search solution for e-commerce for multiple markets.

For price, I specify one price per market. I have about 80 or so markets, so that's 80 prices. There is no way around it. I would probably do the same for ratings and views too. One per market.

In our application we use separate dimensions for **market**, **language** and **country**. A market can be Scandinavia, BeNeLux or Asia-Pacific. You need to clearly define what a market is in your case, and agree with the business which markets you have and how you handle changes. Countries *can* map directly to markets, but it may also differ. Finally, language is usually shared across markets/countries and you usually only have to support 20-25 languages.

Suggested data model

- Id
- TitleEnGb
- TitleDeDe
- TitleFrFr
- ...
- PriceGb
- PriceUs
- PriceNo
- PriceDe
- ...
- RatingsGb
- RatingsUs
- RatingsNo
- RatingsDe
- ...
- DescriptionEnGb
- DescriptionDeDe
- DescriptionFrFr
- ...

I try to illustrate that the Title and Description are *language-specific*. The price and ratings are *market-specific*.

For the 20-25 language-specific properties, you have to think about what analyzers to use. You want to use language-specific analyzers, and preferably the Microsoft analyzers since they have much better linguistics support with full lemmatization and so on.

When you develop your frontend application you have to keep track of which market, country and language you then refer to the specific properties. This is the easiest way to support boosting and so on.

**Per-market index is not recommended**
You could create one index per market. I have gone down this route before. I would not recommend this. This means you have to update 109 indexes every time you add, change or delete an item. And Azure Search supports 50 indexes per service at the most anyways.

Comment: Dan that's a very nice and detailed summary of the index def. I have done something similar clubbing the locales and per market properties inside a complex obj. The problem is that I want to use scoring function based on the rating/views. Now the problem is there can 109 diff. ratings for a singe product corresponding to each market and the scoring profile only supports 8 functions. And ow I will be getting mkt name from the ui, how do I configure the scoring profile and tell it that if market is Canada then boost the Canada based rating while calculating the relevance score